# Conditionally appending to a string in PHP

Tags: php

I have an email form that is working just fine. I would like to add a feature that if certain fields are not filled that it does not send them empty in the email. How can I make these field not show up if they are not filled out. Here is my complete code.

```
$message = 'Hello,<br /><br />

First Name: '.$_POST['first_name'].'<br />

Last Name: '.$_POST['last_name'].'<br />                

Email: '.$_POST['email'].'<br /> 

Address: '.$_POST['address'].'<br /> 

Phone: '.$_POST['phone'].'<br /> 

City: '.$_POST['city'].'<br /> 

State: '.$_POST['state'].'<br /> 

Zip Code: '.$_POST['zipcode'].'<br /> 

Country: '.$_POST['country'].'<br /> 

Preferred Method of Contact: '.$_POST['perferred'].'<br /> 

Comments/Questions:<br />
'.$_POST['description'].'<br /><br />


//This is the section I am speaking about           
Interested in: <br />

'.$_POST['nh_home'].'<br /> 

'.$_POST['nh_lot'].'<br />

'.$_POST['nh_townhouse'].'<br />

'.$_POST['nh_condo'].'<br />

'.$_POST['nh_marina'].'<br />

'.$_POST['nh_beachclub'].'<br />

'.$_POST['nh_resale'].'<br /><br />

 // End Section         



 How did you hear about us? <br />
'.$_POST['how_about'].'<br /> 


;


$to      = 'email@domain.com';
$subject = 'Splash Page';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Meredith Bay <info@website.com>' . "\r\n";        


$send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


if($send){
header('Location: http://www.website.com/thank-you/');
exit;
}
else{
echo "error";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your more complete code looks like this:

```
$email = 'some markup' . $_POST['nh_home'] . '<br />';
$email .= 'some markup' . $_POST['nh_lot'] . '<br />';
$email .= 'some markup' . $_POST['nh_townhouse'] . '<br />';
// etc...
```

You can simply introduce conditional checks in between those:

```
$email = '';
if ($_POST['nh_home']) {
  $email .= 'some markup' . $_POST['nh_home'] . '<br />';
}
if ($_POST['nh_lot']) {
  $email .= 'some markup' . $_POST['nh_lot'] . '<br />';
}
if ($_POST['nh_townhouse']) {
  $email .= 'some markup' . $_POST['nh_townhouse'] . '<br />';
}
// etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check, if the value is not empty:

```
if ($_POST['nh_home'])       echo 'Home:      '.$_POST['nh_home'].'<br />';
if ($_POST['nh_lot'])        echo 'Lot:       '.$_POST['nh_lot'].'<br />';
if ($_POST['nh_townhouse'])  echo 'Townhouse: '.$_POST['nh_townhouse'].'<br />';
if ($_POST['nh_condo'])      echo 'Condo:     '.$_POST['nh_condo'].'<br />';
if ($_POST['nh_marina'])     echo 'Marina:    '.$_POST['nh_marina'].'<br />';
if ($_POST['nh_beachclub'])  echo 'Beachclub: '.$_POST['nh_beachclub'].'<br />';
if ($_POST['nh_resale'])     echo 'Resale:    '.$_POST['nh_resale'].'<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$message = 'Hello,<br /><br />';

if(empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
    $message .= 'First Name: '.$_POST['first_name'].'<br />'
}
```

It's just a basic conditional. Do this for each element in the `POST` data.